# SQL initcap on text[]

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to uppercase all the words in an array of text in my table:

```sql
update locations
set aka  = initcap(aka)
```

But `initcap()` doesn't support text arrays. How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast to `text` and back:

```sql
UPDATE locations
SET    aka = initcap(aka::text)::text[]
WHERE  aka IS DISTINCT FROM initcap(aka::text)::text[];
```

But don't touch rows that wouldn't change, to make it cheaper. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

I assume you are aware the [`initcap()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) does not exactly "uppercase" strings. It ...

> Converts the first letter of each word to upper case and the rest to lower case.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what it does. Thank you!